# yii2 session is not saved login from postman / app

Tags: php, yii2

I am using frontend module in yii2 framework for my website, and so far the website is working good for all things especially the session of login from web interface.

The model handling the login is the LoginForm model

```
    namespace app\models;

    use Yii;
    use yii\base\Model; 

    /**
     * Login form 
     */
    class LoginForm extends Model {
        public function login()
        {
            if ($this->validate()) {
                return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 7200 * 24 * 30 : 7200 * 24 * 30);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

For website the default file for login is in SiteCotroller.php

```
        use yii\web\Controller;
        use frontend\models\ContactForm;

        /**
         * Site controller
         */
        class SiteController extends Controller {
            /**
             * @inheritdoc
             */
            public function behaviors() {
                return [
                    'access' => [
                        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                        'only' => ['logout', 'signup', 'index'],
                        'rules' => [
                            [
                                'actions' => ['signup'],
                                'allow' => true,
                                'roles' => ['?'],
                            ],
                            [
                                'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                                'allow' => true,
                                'roles' => ['@'],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'verbs' => [
                        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                        'actions' => [
                            'logout' => ['post'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ];
            }
            public function actionLogin() {
                $this->layout = 'main';

                if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }

                $model = new LoginForm();
                if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
                    return $this->goBack();
                } else {
                    return $this->render('login', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
                }
            }

        }
```

The login controller is working great for its own interface in the view file.

---

---

Now that I want to access login from app (ionic/angular), I copied this controller for login to AppController.php in the similar frontend folder:

```
    class AppController extends \yii\rest\Controller {

        public function actions() 
        {
            $actions = parent::actions();
            $actions['options'] = [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\OptionsAction',
                // optional:
                'collectionOptions' => ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'resourceOptions' => ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            ];
            return $actions;
        }

        public function actionIndex() {
            echo json_encode("hi"); 
        }

        public static function allowedDomains() {
            return [
                 '*',                        // star allows all domains
                'http://localhost:8100',
                //'http://test2.example.com',
            ];
        }

        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();
            \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
        }

        public function beforeAction($action)
        {
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;


            return parent::beforeAction($action);
        }

        public function behaviors()
        {
            $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
            unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

            // add CORS filter
            $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                'cors' => [
                    'Origin' => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                ],
            ];

            $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
                'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],
            ];

            $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
                'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                'except' => ['login', 'checkuser'],   

                /*
                'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
                'authMethods' => [
                    HttpBasicAuth::className(),

                ],
                'except' => ['login', 'checkuser'],
                */

            ];

            return $behaviors;
        }


        public function actionLogin() {

            $model = new LoginForm();
            $params = Yii::$app->request->post();
            $model->username = $params['username'];
            $model->password = $params['password'];

            if ($model->login()) {
                $user = User::findByUsername($model->username);
                $response['success'] = Yii::$app->user->login($user);
                $response['SessionID'] = Yii::$app->session->getId();
                return $response; 
            } else {
                $response['errors'] = $model->getErrors();
                return $response;
            }
        }
```

The strange is, the action login in this AppController.php is working if I tried to login from app/postman, it returns `true`. However, the session is not saved, and SessionID is empty.

I have been exploring this for three days but still cant figure it out what is the problem.

This is my frontend/config/main.php file

```
        $params = array_merge(
            require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
            require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
            require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
            require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
        );

        return [
            'id' => 'app-frontend',
            'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',
            'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
            'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
            'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
            'layout' => 'admin',
            'components' => [ 
                'request' => [
                    'parsers' => [
                        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
                    ], 
                    'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
                ],
                'user' => [
                    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
                    'enableAutoLogin' => false,
                    'enableSession' => true,
                    'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true, 'lifetime' => 3600 * 4],
                    'loginUrl' => ['site/login'],
                ],
                'session' => [
                    'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
                ],
```

[image]

When I access the url directly into the yii2 web domain, I got this `_csrf-frontend` and `advanced-frontend` value in browser Cookies. But from app I dont get any.

Please I really appreciate the help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Good morning klaudia. Please verify whether your session is open. Maybe it is not...

Comment: Good Morning, Damian. Thank you. I have tried to this `\Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;` but it doesnt even matther.

Comment: By doing this you are disabling the session! Please `\Yii::$app->user->enableSession = true;` and also please do `\Yii::$app->session->open();` to open the session :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve session from another app it is bound to domain. So what should you probably do is to handle that logic separate in your Ionic application which I think is preferred way. Or you can do it by storing sessions in DB (there is Yii class for that) and than handle it through extra requests (which is bad approach).